# How to return a custom response object from the Django rest framework's custom Authentication class

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, captcha

I have scrached my head over this for almost 3-4 days.

Let me explain the situation. I have a DRF(Django REST Framework) class based view with a custom authentication class. As far as I understand, you can override the authenticate method of DRF's BaseAuthentication class to implement your custom authentication, while you can only raise predefined Exceptions provided from DRF if the authentication fails.

My problem is, I am trying to find a way to return custom response i.e; the captcha HTML to the frontend directly from the authentication class, so as to achieve no authentication related code in my view.

To have a better understanding of my situation I am providing a pseudo code below.

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (ExampleCustomAuth, )

    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

This is the view and this part is absolutely fine.

```
class ExampleCustomAuth(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        req = request
        request = req._request
        {
            This part of code decides if its required for a 
            captcha or not 
        }

        if captcha_required:
            response = HttpResponse()
            response.status_code = 401
            response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Captcha" id="%s"'% (id)
            response.content = loader.render_to_string('captcha.html')

            return response # This is where it goes wrong
```

I believe, its not possible to return a response right from here.

I hope someone has figured a way around this.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally figured a way to get it working.

According to the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication), the authenticate method should be overridden for any authentication logic and also have to override the authenticate_header, so that if you raise an exception in authenticate method, you can return a string from the authenticate_header method, which will be used as a value for the www-Authenticate header.

Below is how the implementation works.

```
class ExampleCustomAuth(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        req = request
        request = req._request
        {
            This part of code decides if its required for a 
            captcha or not 
        }

        if captcha_required:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(loader.render_to_string('captcha.html'))

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'Captcha" id="%s"'% (id)
```